# Uploading a File to GCS using boto in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, multifile-uploader

I'm trying to upload files from my local system to the GCS using boto in cloud.  After a file get uploaded I get an error which says " The MD5 you specified in Content-MD5 or x-goog-hash did not match what we computed."  Below is my code.

```
def upload():
    bucket_name = 'bucketname'
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    fpic = Key(bucket)
    d='E:/Eclipse/workspace/Files'
    for filename in os.listdir(d):
        contents=d + '/' + filename
        fpic.key = 'my-files'+filename
        fpic.set_contents_from_filename(contents, {}, replace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to upload the files from local to GCS using boto. Find the link below [1]. Try that it will work for you without any error.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary#credentials